# decorrelation of variables and PCA

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, correlation, pca

I need to run regression analysis with respect to two different scalar predictors, say `A` and `B`, stored in the array `values`. These two predictors are however highly correlated with one another, so I was told to first decorrelate them through PCA. I am most definitely not an expert on PCA, but what I did so far is the following:

```
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

values = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [10, 11, 12, 13, 14])

# step 1: scale both variables
valuesZ = StandardScaler().fit_transform(values)

# PCA decomposition
model = PCA(whiten=True) 
pcaA = model.fit_transform(valuesZ) #fit the model
```

Now, as far as I understand, the array `pcaA` returns a numpy array of decorrelated values for two principal components, out of which the first one representing the most of the variance between the two original variables -- right? If so, I wonder whether the two components can still be considered decorrelated (transformed) variables that can be eventually used for regression. In some paper I am referring to, the authors name the two decorrelated (transformed) values `A-against-B` and `B-against-A`, which sounds confusing to me given the above.

So, I was hoping someone could give me a hint in the right direction. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of issues:

- `Bz = StandardScaler().fit_transform(A)` should be `Bz = StandardScaler().fit_transform(B)`
- `pcaA = model.fit_transform(Az)`: you are transforming one predictor only.

If you do the following:

```
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import pearsonr

A = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
B = np.array([10, 22, 29, 41, 33])

print(f'Original correlation: {pearsonr(A, B)[0]}')

array = np.zeros((A.size, 2))
array[:, 0] = A
array[:, 1] = B

# step 1: scale both variables
scaled_array = StandardScaler().fit_transform(array)

# PCA decomposition
model = PCA()
pca = model.fit_transform(scaled_array)  # fit the model

print(f'New correlation: {pearsonr(pca[:, 0], pca[:, 1])[0]}')
```

Output:

```
Original correlation: 0.8764598212022146
New correlation: -5.551115123125783e-17
```

you will end up with uncorrelated variables, which can then be used for regression.

Comment: Yes, of course there were a couple of typos in the question (which I have now edited accordingly). Apart from that, it sounds like you are confirming that the output values of the `pca` array are uncorrelated variables (= the principal components). Correct? Is it then okay to consider the two components of `pca` as `A-against-B` and `B-against-A`?

Comment: Yes by construction the principal components are uncorrelated. I am not sure what you mean by `A-against-B`.

Comment: I am not sure either -- haha. I am trying to making sense of a paper I am reading. The authors say that they used PCA to decorrelate variables and they name these decorrelated variables `A-against-B` and `B-against-A`.